# How do go to Activity form a recycleview fragment

Tags: java, android, visual-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8aNh.png)

I am in home fragment currently and needed to go to pdf activity .

Comment: Please put the code in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Transaction Between fragmnet and activity you can simply use intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), mFragmentFavorite.class);

startActivity(intent);

From an Activity

Intent intent = new Intent(this, mFragmentFavorite.class);

startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

On line number 90, instead of `MainActivity.this`, simply write `this` or `getActivity()`

```
new Intent(this, mFragmentFavorite.class)
```

Or

```
new Intent(getActivity(), mFragmentFavorite.class)
```